# Firefox not syncing properly on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, firefox, sync

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 this morning.
I usually set my browser up when I'm on a new *Operating System*. So I open Firefox version 62.0.3 and sign in successfully. However, only my ad-blocker and one book mark were synced. No other extension or even my *Bookmark Toolbar* synced.

I disconnected my account and deleted any remaining info. Then I Purged Firefox and did a reinstall - but this changed nothing.

I would greatly appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your devices need to be on the new version of Sync in order for them to share information with each other. If any of your devices are still on the old Sync, you must unlink them before setting them up with the new Sync. Please see Sync your Firefox bookmarks, history, passwords and more for step-by-step instructions.

Helpful Links:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-sync-troubleshooting-and-tips#w_i-set-up-firefox-sync-but-nothing-is-syncing

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/sync-your-firefox-bookmarks-history-passwords-and-